# Drupal 7 date_popup : Howto align label to date field on the same line with label on the left

Tags: forms, datetime

I'm using FORM API with Drupal 7.
I try to align label with a date_popup field on the same line on the form, with the label on the left of the date field.
I can only align the label on the right of the date_popup field . See 
[Actual layout](http://homepage.bluewin.ch/dhz/img/capture.png)
My code looks actualy like that :

`function test_form_dateselect($form, &$form_state) {`

```
$from = strtotime('-48 hour');
$to   = time();

$form['period'] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="period">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',          
);
$form['period']['datebloc'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Choisissez la période à afficher'),  
);
$form['period']['datebloc']['start'] = array(
        '#title' => 'Début de la période&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',
        '#type' => 'date_popup', 
        '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $from),
        '#date_format' => 'd.m.Y H:i:s',
        '#date_label_position' => 'within',
        '#required' => TRUE, 
);
$form['period']['datebloc']['end'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_popup', 
        '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $to),
        '#date_format' => 'd.m.Y H:i:s',
        '#date_label_position' => 'within',
        '#title' => 'Fin de la période&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',
        '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required
            );  
$form['period']['submit_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Afficher'),
);  
return  $form;
```

Any idea or help would be appreciated !

The problem seems to be related with the "date_popup" type. If I try to replace "date_popup" with the "date" type, the label is correctly aligned on the left of the field ...